# Django How to only show user's own posts when logged in?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and made a simple app the would let the users to make six picks of a list of names to vote for the top six. The problem that I'm having is that any user when logged in they can see everyone else's votes! How can I have the logged user(no the admin) to only see their votes and not everyone's?
I have been reading on here and it looks like it can be done with querysets? but want' able to get the idea deployed.

I have two classes in my model.py:

```
class CandidateName(models.Model):
    canidate_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.canidate_name; 

class Vote(models.Model):
    first_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name= 'first')
    second_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='second')
    third_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='third')
    fourth_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='fourth')
    fifith_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='fifth')
    sixth_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='sixth')
```

Comment: How have you made the connection between the Vote table and the user table?

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like adding a User field to your Vote class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    first_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name= 'first')
    second_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='second')
    third_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='third')
    fourth_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='fourth')
    fifith_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='fifth')
    sixth_pick = models.ForeignKey(CandidateName, related_name='sixth')
```

Then in your views.py retrieve the Votes associated with the currently logged in user and pass those to your template.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    votes_by_user = Vote.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```